# Deserializate only certain JSON tags with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Is there a way that I dont have to extract the tags I need "manually" from the JSON if I don't want to deserialize all of them so that I can use this constructor?

```
public class Tweet {
    public String username;
    public String message;
    public String image_url;

    @JsonCreator
    public Tweet(
            @JsonProperty("from_user")          String username,
            @JsonProperty("text")               String message,
            @JsonProperty("profile_image_url")  String url) {
        this.username = username;
        this.message = message;
        this.image_url = url;
    }
}
```

And here it is the JSON:

```
   {
         "created_at":"Wed, 15 Aug 2012 18:17:55 +0000",
         "from_user":"felix_panda",
         "from_user_id":132396774,
         "from_user_id_str":"132396774",
         "from_user_name":"felix suganda",
         "geo":null,
         "id":235802515571101696,
         "id_str":"235802515571101696",
         "iso_language_code":"en",
         "metadata":{
            "result_type":"recent"
         },
         "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2393214158\/profile_normal.jpg",
         "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2393214158\/profile_normal.jpg",
         "source":"&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/www.tweetcaster.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;TweetCaster for Android&lt;\/a&gt;",
         "text":"@Android how do u fix you lost your data connection because you left home network with data roaming (cont) http:\/\/t.co\/4coRjaXT",
     "to_user":"Android",
     "to_user_id":382267114,
     "to_user_id_str":"382267114",
     "to_user_name":"Android"
```

This is the error I get when deserializing it:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "created_at"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you want to [disable](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#disable%28com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature%29) [FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES).

Answer (score 1):

I am using MongoJack. Here is what I did to solve it.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    MongoJackModule.configure(mapper);
    JacksonDBCollection<Message, Long> coll = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(dbCollection, Message.class, Long.class, mapper);
```